# Validating html5 offline in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I've been trying to search for a way to validate html files on an offline machine, but most of my findings are for ways to do so online or they were older answers with py2. I have found someone mention that [html5validator](https://github.com/svenkreiss/html5validator) may be helpful, but this looks like it would only work from a command line, and I would want to  initialize the validation from within my script. Is there a way to do this offline?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=validate+html+from+python+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: You can run command line application within a Python script.

Comment: @FanchenBao I did not know that, I'll do some research on how to do that :) Thank you

Comment: @mplungjan I did look around, but found most of the responses are for online use. However I did stumble upon beautifulsoup which may be helpful and I'll be looking into it. Thank you

Comment: How about checking out [html5-parser](https://html5-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @JonSG Thank you :) I looked into this and it looks promising! Though I can't tell fi this would also validate html, do you know if it does?